# Django, how to reject a object from a @receiver if some int equals to another int

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm having this doubt, I have a model that stores data from a form, when the data is sent this `@receiver` stores the data in another model.

```
class Invitados(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Invitados"

    estados = (
        ("Permitido", "Permitido"),
        ("Prohibido", "Prohibido"),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los nombre/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los apellido/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    tipo_de_cedula = models.CharField(max_length= 2, null=False, blank=False)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d')], error_messages={'invalid': 'La cedula solo puede contener caracteres numericos (0-9)'})
    estado = models.CharField(max_length= 10, choices=estados, default='Permitido', null=False, blank=False)
    envio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Invitaciones(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Invitaciones"
        unique_together = (("cedula", "fecha"),)

    tipos_cedula = (
        ("V", "V"),
        ("E", "E"),
    )
    estados = (
        ("Disponible", "Disponible"),
        ("Usado", "Usado"),
    )
    def random_string():
        return str(random.randint(10000, 9999999))

    def validar_cedula(obj):
        cedula = obj
        cedula_invitados = Invitados.objects.filter(estado='Prohibido')
        for c in cedula_invitados:
            if str(cedula) == str(c.cedula):
               raise ValidationError("La cedula que has ingresado pertenece a una persona que tiene prohibido acceder al club.")     

    año = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los nombre/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los apellido/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d'), validar_cedula], error_messages={'invalid': 'La cedula solo puede contener caracteres numericos (0-9)'})
    tipo_de_cedula = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tipos_cedula, default="V", null=False, blank=False)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=10, default = random_string, null=False, blank=False, editable=False, unique=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=estados, default="Disponible", null=False, blank=False)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(datetime.date(año, 12, 31),message="No puedes elegir una fecha que este mas alla de este año"), validators.MinValueValidator(datetime.date.today(),message="No puedes elegir una fecha anterior a la de hoy")])
    envio = models.DateField(auto_now=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitaciones)
def crear_invitado(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Invitados.objects.create(nombre=instance.nombre, apellido=instance.apellido, tipo_de_cedula=instance.tipo_de_cedula, cedula=instance.cedula)
```

I want this receiver to create the object only if  there is not another object with the same `instance.cedula` in it.

I tried to make a for cicle throught all the objects in `Intivados.cedula` like this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitaciones)
def crear_invitado(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    data = Invitados.objects.all()
    for c in data:
        if int(c.cedula) == int(instance.cedula):
            cedula_invitacion = print("This person already exists")
        else: 
            cedula_invitacion = Invitados.objects.create(nombre=instance.nombre, apellido=instance.apellido, tipo_de_cedula=instance.tipo_de_cedula, cedula=instance.cedula)
    if created: 
        cedula_invitacion
```

This does not seem to work, the else statement is always stored in the model multiple times (equal to the quantity of models inside data) and also the print(), show the same has the quantity of models inside data.

If someone has a answer, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Show your both models

Comment: Delete your answer and accept my edit, you should not add question into answer, you need to update existing question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `filter` with [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) to check if objects with specific parameters exist in DB:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitaciones)
def crear_invitado(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created and not Invitados.objects.filter(cedula=instance.cedula).exists():
       Invitados.objects.create(nombre=instance.nombre, apellido=instance.apellido, tipo_de_cedula=instance.tipo_de_cedula, cedula=instance.cedula)
```

Comment: @AnupYadav yes, this will work if `cedula` is manytomany field.But not in other situations.

Comment: I get 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'exist',

Comment: @César sorry, it's typo, should be `exists()`.

Comment: Oh, i did not saw the typo, it works, my question was the opposite so i created the object ins the else statement, thanks, lots of bytes and love from Venezuela :)

Comment: @César yes I realized that, check my update, I just added `not` to condition: `if created and not Invitados.objects.filter(cedula=instance.cedula).exists():`

Answer (score 0):

This is the both models.

```
class Invitados(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Invitados"

    estados = (
        ("Permitido", "Permitido"),
        ("Prohibido", "Prohibido"),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los nombre/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los apellido/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    tipo_de_cedula = models.CharField(max_length= 2, null=False, blank=False)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d')], error_messages={'invalid': 'La cedula solo puede contener caracteres numericos (0-9)'})
    estado = models.CharField(max_length= 10, choices=estados, default='Permitido', null=False, blank=False)
    envio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Invitaciones(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Invitaciones"
        unique_together = (("cedula", "fecha"),)

    tipos_cedula = (
        ("V", "V"),
        ("E", "E"),
    )
    estados = (
        ("Disponible", "Disponible"),
        ("Usado", "Usado"),
    )
    def random_string():
        return str(random.randint(10000, 9999999))

    def validar_cedula(obj):
        cedula = obj
        cedula_invitados = Invitados.objects.filter(estado='Prohibido')
        for c in cedula_invitados:
            if str(cedula) == str(c.cedula):
               raise ValidationError("La cedula que has ingresado pertenece a una persona que tiene prohibido acceder al club.")     

    año = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los nombre/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^[A-z]')], error_messages={'invalid': 'El/los apellido/s solo puede contener caracteres del alfabeto (A-Z)'})
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d'), validar_cedula], error_messages={'invalid': 'La cedula solo puede contener caracteres numericos (0-9)'})
    tipo_de_cedula = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tipos_cedula, default="V", null=False, blank=False)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=10, default = random_string, null=False, blank=False, editable=False, unique=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=estados, default="Disponible", null=False, blank=False)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(datetime.date(año, 12, 31),message="No puedes elegir una fecha que este mas alla de este año"), validators.MinValueValidator(datetime.date.today(),message="No puedes elegir una fecha anterior a la de hoy")])
    envio = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitaciones)
def crear_invitado(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    data = Invitados.objects.all()
    for c in data:
        if int(c.cedula) == int(instance.cedula):
            cedula_invitacion = print("Esta invitado ya existe")
        else: 
            cedula_invitacion = Invitados.objects.create(nombre=instance.nombre, apellido=instance.apellido, tipo_de_cedula=instance.tipo_de_cedula, cedula=instance.cedula)
    if created: 
        cedula_invitacion
```